# Compute the number of pick-ups and drop-offs for each hour of the day and every day of the week from DB

Tags: postgresql, qgis

I need to compute the number of pick-ups and drop-offs for each hour of the day and every day of the week from the below database.

I tried to apply below query but i guess it is very basic

select date, in_service from aid_atidivyakumarpatra;

[click here to see the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPSD6.jpg)

Comment: Post the table as text.

Comment: I am not able to post the table on the post, that's why I kept the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the results you are looking for.  There are plenty of examples out there to give you a more verbose date that shows day of the week so I did not focus on that.  The answer was in the Group by statement.

SELECT Convert(DATE, date) as Day, DATEPART(HOUR, date) as Hour,
COUNT (CASE inservice WHEN 'drop' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS DropOffs,
COUNT (CASE inservice WHEN 'pick' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS PickUps
FROM PickupDropoff
GROUP BY Convert(DATE, date), DATEPART(HOUR, date)

I made this answer in Microsoft SQL Server, if you are using Postgres hopefully there is an equivalent.

Comment: Thank you charles for the query. I have used timestamp without time zone datatype while creating my table. So, when I run your query I received below error in postgresql DB :ERROR:  function convert(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Comment: If I use below simple query just to group it by date, I am getting the result. SELECT pg_catalog.date(date), COUNT (CASE in_service WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS DropOffs, COUNT (CASE in_service WHEN false THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS PickUps FROM aid_atidivyakumarpatra GROUP BY pg_catalog.date(date);

Comment: I am not able to convert the timestamp dataype into date and hour in your query

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using Postgres SQL I'm using MS SQL Server.  I am seeing that timestamp can be quite different from DATETIME in MS SQL it's not even really a date.  I would consider converting my timestamp to a true DATETIME before trying to extract the date and the hour.  Keep in mind I've given you the logic but the syntax in Postgress will be different from what I've given.  Please look up convert timestamp to datetime then try to get the individual parts of Date, Hour. and please mark me if I've helped you. thanks.